# Openstack installation issue on ubuntu-18.04

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, openstack, devstack

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS \n \l
```

I'm following this [Link](https://www.journaldev.com/30037/install-openstack-ubuntu-devstack) to install `Openstack` using `Devstack`. However `git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack` master branch's `./stack.sh` fails with below error.

```
+./stack.sh:main:230                       SUPPORTED_DISTROS='bullseye|focal|f34|opensuse-15.2|opensuse-tumbleweed|rhel8|rhel9|openEuler-20.03'
+./stack.sh:main:232                       [[ ! bionic =~ bullseye|focal|f34|opensuse-15.2|opensuse-tumbleweed|rhel8|rhel9|openEuler-20.03 ]]

WARNING: this script has not been tested on bionic
+./stack.sh:main:234                       [[ '' != \y\e\s ]]
+./stack.sh:main:235                       die 235 'If you wish to run this script anyway run with FORCE=yes'
+functions-common:die:253                  local exitcode=0
+functions-common:die:254                  set +o xtrace
[Call Trace]
./stack.sh:235:die
[ERROR] ./stack.sh:235 If you wish to run this script anyway run with FORCE=yes
/opt/stack/devstack/functions-common: line 299: /opt/stack/logs/error.log: No such file or directory
```

Even `./stack.sh FORCE=yes` and `stable/newton, stable/pike, stable/victoria & stable/xena` branch also results the same above error.

Does the support for `Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (bionic)` deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the support for Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (bionic) deprecated?

Not exactly.

As a general rule, the latest version of the script targets the latest supported (by Openstack) versions of the host operating systems.  Older versions *may work*.  But there might be minor issues ... that someone with the ability to read / diagnose shell scripts ought to be able to figure out.

If you need a version of the script that explicitly supports (say) Bionic, there will be one in the Git6 repo history.

<sup>(This is in line with general OpenStack Ubuntu support.  The latest OpenStack release is Wallably and Wallaby no longer supports Bionic.  The Bionic -> Focal cross-over release of Openstack was Ussuri; see https://ubuntu.com/openstack/docs/supported-versions.  Note that Devstack is not an official OpenStack product, but they are effectively forced to track the "supported release" rules, at least loosely.)</sup>

---

The version of the Devstack script that you checked out does not explicitly supports Focal rather than Bionic.

If you look at https://opendev.org/openstack/devstack/src/branch/master/stack.sh on line 230, it currently says:

```
# Warn users who aren't on an explicitly supported distro, but allow them to
# override check and attempt installation with ``FORCE=yes ./stack``
SUPPORTED_DISTROS="bullseye|focal|f34|opensuse-15.2|opensuse-tumbleweed|rhel8|rhel9|openEuler-20.03"
```

If you want a version of devstack that explicitly supports bionic, use `git blame` (or whatever) to track changes to the `SUPPORTED_DISTROS` line.  You should be able to find some versions where `FORCE` is not necessary.

---

On the other hand .... the error message:

```
/opt/stack/devstack/functions-common: line 299: /opt/stack/logs/error.log: 
     No such file or directory
```

implies that the script is assuming that a file or directory already exists.  You could probably just create it / them by hand.  (It is clearly just a log file / directory.)